# problem while trying to run heat on openstack ERROR: None

Tags: openstack, heat, openstack-heat

so i followed this documentation :

https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_20.04&p=openstack_victoria3&f=6

https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_20.04&p=openstack_victoria3&f=7

https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_20.04&p=openstack_victoria3&f=8

when i type this command as root :

```
openstack orchestration service list
```

the output is :

```
ERROR: None
```

Comment: I suggest an internet search. Hot tip: https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/122332/stein-on-rhel76-openstack-orchestration-service-list-return-error-none/.

Comment: thank you for your reply i already did an internet search an i already opened that link before writing this post and sadly it didn't help

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know what you have already tried. I would add the --debug option, and also try to issue the API myself. Perhaps the official documentation at docs.openstack.org/heat/victoria is better?